# Using a command's output as `paste` input without temporary files

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash scripting and I have what I assume a very novice question.

How would I go about concatenating the output of the following 3 commands into a single line of code?

The line below gets the current system date minus 1 day (24hrs) and any files greater than current date -1 day get written to redir_bbtrm_files.txt

```
awk -v date="$(date -d "-1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" '$3$4<date' sftp_bbtrm_files.txt \
  > redir_bbtrm_files.txt
```

The line below prints date, time and file name from redir_bbtrm_files.txt and redirects output to bbtrm_filenames_n_time.txt

```
awk '{print $3,$4,$5}'  redir_bbtrm_files.txt > bbtrm_filenames_n_time.txt
```

The line below appends file names, time, and reference numbers. email_final_bbtrm_output.txt is the output that will be in the notification

```
paste -d ' ' bbtrm_filenames_n_time.txt bbtrm_ref.txt > email_final_bbtrm_output.txt
```

Basically, I am using the commands above to save off the output of each command in a file and then appending the results at the end. But I would imagine that this is not a good way to do this and there must be some other way to handle this scenario in a more efficient way.

Can the above be done in 1 line of code and maybe save off the output into a single file?

Comment: "Concatenating" isn't exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: I think this line `paste -d ' ' bbtrm_filenames_n_time.txt bbtrm_ref.txt > email_final_bbtrm_output.txt` gives me the output of both files into one. Which all I'm really trying to do is to write the output of both files next to each other (concatenating?) But I'd like to do all 3 commands above in one shot, if possible.

Comment: Yes, but concatenating them would be putting one after the other, not putting them alongside. And that's not even the interesting/tricky part of your question ("tricky" meaning "requiring extensions not present in POSIX sh to perform without named pipes").

Comment: What I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible, since your shell is bash (which has those extensions). I mean, I posted an answer, didn't I? :)

Comment: ...and, as I also stated above, you could do it even in POSIX sh if you were willing to have a longer, harder-to-write answer that created named pipes as temporary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done as a single command, assuming your shell is bash. Assuming that I'm reading your question correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; also must not be run with "sh yourscript" (use "bash yourscript")

paste -d ' ' \
  <(awk -v date="$(date -d "-1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" '$3$4<date' sftp_bbtrm_files.txt \
    | awk '{print $3,$4,$5}') \
  bbtrm_ref.txt \
  >email_final_bbtrm_output.txt
```

---

To explain:

- `foo | bar` connects the stdout of `foo` to the stdin of `bar`; thus, it can be used to send the output of your first `awk` to your second one (though *why* you need two separate awk commands there rather than only one is a bit unclear).
- `<(...)` is an expansion which is replaced with a filename (either a named pipe or a `/dev/fd` reference) which, when read, returns the output of the command `...`

Thus, we're `paste`ing together both `bbtrm_ref.txt` and the result of sending `sftp_bbtrm_files.txt` through your two `awk` commands to get your single output file.

Comment: `<(echo "Header 1"; awk ...)`, and likewise, replace `bbtrm_ref.txt` with `<(echo "Header 2"; cat bbtrm_ref.txt)`. Adjust `Header 1` and `Header 2` appropriately.

Comment: I am getting the following error after running your script. `awk: (FILENAME=/tmp/sftp_bbtrm_files.txt FNR=2) fatal: cannot open file ` ' for reading (No such file or directory)` File exists, permissions are set. I tried to run it from a .sh file not directly in Linux.

Comment: That error is clearly not from "my script"; there's no `FILENAME=` in my code. By the way, using `.sh` extensions on bash scripts is bad practice -- it implies POSIX sh compatibility, and means that if you rewrite in a different language you'd need to change the filename (and thus modify all callers) to have that name no longer be misleading.

Comment: If you're having trouble adapting the advice I'm giving to your real code, that's not a thing I can help with unless I can see your real code, or at least a [minimal reproducer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem. If you ask a new question on the subject, feel free to @-notify me in a comment to it.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I fixed my script. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: this is what I have `paste -d ' ' \
  <( echo "H1                       H2       H3 "; awk -v date="$(date -d "-1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" '$3$4<date' sftp_bbtrm_files.txt \
    | awk '{print $5,$3,$4}') \
  <(echo "H4  H5."; cat bbtrm_pmt_ref.txt) \
  > email_final_bbtrm_output.txt` When I try to email the email_final_output.txt I get this output as the email body:  H1                                  H2               H3      H4    H5
FileName1_2688308.pdf 2016-08-15 09:40 ID1 17507 FileName2_2696553.dat 2016-08-24 05:13 ID2 17528.It prints 1 string

Comment: I would want to have headers listed and then the list of files underneath. I am using this command to send the email `cat email_final_bbtrm_output.txt | mailx -s "Subject" "$email"`

Comment: `cat filename | mailx ...` is always bad form; use `mailx ... <filename` to avoid the overhead of a separate `cat` process. That said, in your case here there's no need for a temporary file at all, since you can pipe directly from `paste` into `mailx`. As for the headers, I've already told you how to do that.